# Multiple model updates in sails waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm building a project on sails (0.10.0-rc5) for a few days and in a few cases i need to update multiple entries at once with the same data so I made something up ...

```
Servers.find({owner_id: anonymous_user.id}).exec(function(error, servers) {

  catches.error(error);
  queries.save_each(servers, {owner_id: user.id});

});
```

The interesting part is queries.save_each() which I created ...

```
/**
 * Save each ActiveRecord objects with the desired attributes
 * @param  {object} objects ActiveRecord object (e.g. servers, users)
 * @param  {object} updates datas to update
 * @return {void}
 */
save_each  = function(objects, updates) {

// For each object we will update the wanted datas
for (var n in objects) {

    objects[n] = variables.inject(objects[n], updates);
    objects[n].save(function(error) { 

        catches.error(error);

     });

}

}
```

Basically, it's checking each entry and updating it from the new datas with save(). It works fine, but i'm wondering if there's nothing already done in waterline to do so ; I didn't find anything, but i'm quite beginner in sails maybe i missed something !

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the Sails docs, particularly for [.update()](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelMethods.md#update-criteria--criteria--callback-)?

Comment: some difficulties to check the doc and that's how you make a whole useless system ! thanks ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, to update records in Sails, use the `update` method:

```
Model.update(criteria, data).exec(callback);
```

for example:

```
Servers.update({owner_id: anonymous_user.id}, {owner_id: user.id})
       .exec(function(err, updatedServers) {
                 // do something
             });
```

Documentation for `update` is on the [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/update.html).

Comment: It seems like the docs are pretty empty.  Where did you find this?

Comment: Hi Mattblang, The docs used to be awesome but they changed since v0.10, in the new docs click on the three items at the top - Anatomy reference and concepts.

Comment: But how do we retain existing data while updating? I don't want to override them.

Comment: The `update` method will only overwrite the data supplied as the second argument.  Any fields you don't specify in that argument will remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Here we have a set of Photos, which we want to update.

```
var photos= [1,2,5]; //update the status of these 3 photos at once!
var values = {status:"accepted"};

Photo.update(photos,values).exec(function afterwards(err, updated){

       if (err) {
                res.json(err)
                return;
       }
       res.json({err:"Everything worked"})
 });
```